# Transform numeric array in associative in order to access it from html template

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Alright, my data gets stored in a file using the same pattern:

> id|title|content

I created a function which explodes the entries by the delimiter '|' into an array.

```
function get_entries(){

$retAr = array();

$data = file_get_contents("db/entries.log");

$lines = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line

foreach($lines as $line){

    $retAr[] = explode('|', $line );

}

return array_reverse( $retAr );
}

Accessable in html:

<?php foreach(get_entries() as $entry): ?>
  <a class='title'><?php echo $entry[1];?></a>
  <p class='content'><?php echo $entry[2];?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Okay, it works so far but I want to access the data using an associative array pretty much like this.

```
<?php foreach(transform_to_assoc(get_entries()) as $entry): ?>
  <a class='title'><?php echo $entry['title'];?></a>
  <p class='content'><?php echo $entry['content'];?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Related function I've written:

```
function transform_to_assoc($num_array){

$keys = array('id', 'title', 'content');
$assoc = array();

foreach ($num_array as $data) {

  foreach ($keys as $key)  {

   $assoc[$key] = $data;

  }

}

return $assoc;

}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Maybe I got something wrong, but I'm sure my approach was the right one. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do what you want:

```
function transform_to_assoc($num_array){
    $keys = array('id', 'title', 'content');
    $assoc = array();

    foreach ($keys as $k=>$key)  {
        $assoc[$key] = $num_array[$k];
    }

    return $assoc;
}
```

Edit:

To use this for a multi dimensional array do the following:

```
$arr = array(
    array(0, 'test heading 1', 'test content 1'),
    array(1, 'test heading 1', 'test content 1'),
);

$newArray = array();

foreach($arr as $a) {
    $newArray[] = transform_to_assoc($a);
}

function transform_to_assoc($num_array){
    $keys = array('id', 'title', 'content');
    $assoc = array();

    foreach ($keys as $k=>$key)  {
        $assoc[$key] = $num_array[$k];
    }

    return $assoc;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a nice solution, but it does not work for me. I always get the  'Illegal string offset' warning :/

Comment: Ok then, in the very first line of the transform_to_assoc() function can you add 'var_dump($num_array);' and tell me what output it gives you.

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> string(8) "Headline" [2]=> string(12) "Content test" }
Maybe I just screwed up, since I'm at school and did a single numeric array  but I guess your solution will work since my function was returning like $post[0][$key]

Comment: I've tested the code above and it does work, so the issue must be with some other part of your code. Can you post the exact error log entry and the secion of code it applies to?

Comment: It does work, thanks mate! :) Everythings working fine, but I should rather take a look at a good php book :D Btw, do you have any idea of a source where I can learn php like you can code it? I'm just a beginner. :/

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/ ignore the books, read that and have a play around. Make sure you read and understand the OWASP Top 10, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10. And always use the PDO library (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database queries. That's the best advice I can give you in a comment form...

Comment: Short question Garry, your function does work perfectly, when the array is not multidimensional. But when it is the arrays can't get printed correctly by using your function like this foreach( transform_to_assoc(get_posts() ) as $post ) | Result using print_r was: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Another Test [2] => This is a test lala ) 1 Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => Hello World by denii [2] => This is a test ) 1

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `list` construct. Just exchange the first foreach loop with this:

```
foreach($lines as $i => $line){
  list($retAr[$i]['id'], $retAr[$i]['title'], $retAr[$i]['content']) =  explode('|', $line );
}
```